# Daemon thread implementation

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm working on a project in java.I have implemented most of it.It has 7 different classes(in all of them i have used threads) that relate to each other .One of those has the main method .So i'm asked to use a deamon thread in the main class so that it will initialize all the other threads on the other classes.

```
Question : How can i implement the daemon thread in the main class?
```

Answer (score 3):

`main` thread is created for you and you have no control over whether it's a daemon or not. And it wouldn't have much sense. But you *do* have control over all threads you create. Simply use [`setDaemon()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon%28boolean%29) method:

```
Thread thread = new MyFancyThread();
thread.setDaemon(true);
thread.start();
```

Do the same thing for all your custom threads. Make sure you understand the consequences: with this setup once `main` thread finishes (you exit `main()` method) your whole application will terminate.

Comment: got it .just one question..i have a power up and a quit command on my main...since on the power up command i'm gonna initialize this daemon thread does this mean that on the quit command i'll have to use thread.setDaemon(false) ?

Comment: @Joni: does *quit*` command you should terminate your whole application? Then simply return from `main`, all non-daemon threads will terminate automatically.

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz: Actually all *daemons* will terminate automatically when main terminates. The main thread cannot exit if there are non-daemon threads still running.